# python pandas perform calculation based on condition

Tags: python, pandas

I have some challenge in my work regarding working with pandas.

I have a pandas dataframe with columns `Time, x, y, a, b`.

For simplicity, the dataframe has 5 records, from which 3 records are fully filled (`Time, x,y,a,b` has data). Other 2 `a,b` are empty.  **Time is unidirectional**

I'd like to perform a calculation on some condition on `Time` (lets say `Time > 3`) and store result on `a` and `b` (lets say the functions are `a=x^2, b=x^3`). The calculation of `a,b` shall be performed in single function (I'm using lambda function). For example

```
Time    x   y       a        b
0.3     0   1     2.0      3.0
1.5     4   5     6.0      7.0
2.8     8   9    10.0     11.0
3.3     8  13    None     None
4.5     3  17    None     None
```

Shall be converted to

```
Time    x   y       a        b
0.3     0   1     2.0      3.0
1.5     4   5     6.0      7.0
2.8     8   9    10.0     11.0
3.3     8  13    64.0    512.0
4.5     3  17     9.0     27.0
```

Any assistance would be appreciated

Notes:

- number of records here are for simplicity and the code shall be general
  for every number of records.
- need that the code will be optimized for performance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure - you can use `.loc` with a suitable filter to select the rows and columns to work on, e.g.:

```
df.loc[df['x'] > 10, ['a', 'b']] = (
    df.loc[df['x'] > 10, 'x'].map(lambda x: (x ** 2, x ** 3))
)
```

Note how returning a tuple from the lambda and having `['a', 'b']` in the assignment side lets you do both calculations at once.

Comment: My data, functions are more complicate, but this shall be more than enough for me in order to continue

Comment: Which pandas version did you use? `map` doesn't allow unpacking in the latest version. Also constructing a Series of tuples with apply/map is not vectorized.

Comment: @mozway pandas version 1.3.5

Comment: @user1977050 my question was originally for AKX. That said, this is a very old version, you should consider updating ;) Keep in mind that this solution is both inefficient and doesn't work on a recent pandas. You said in the question that you needed an efficient approach, `map` is not.

Answer (score 0):

Use simple [boolean indexing](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) and vectorial code:

```
m = df['Time'].gt(3)
x = df.loc[m, 'x']

df.loc[m, 'a'] = x**2
df.loc[m, 'b'] = x**3
```

Output:

```
   Time  x   y     a      b
0   0.3  0   1   2.0    3.0
1   1.5  4   5   6.0    7.0
2   2.8  8   9  10.0   11.0
3   3.3  8  13  64.0  512.0
4   4.5  3  17   9.0   27.0
```

Comparison of efficiency with a `map` (without assignment as this raises a TypeError anyway on pandas 2.0.1):

[image]

Comment: The example is simplified. In my case, the values of `a,b` are calculated based on some other values of the data frame, which are not related to x and may be based on object values (i.e. if `c='LOSS' then b='TEST'`)

Comment: @user1977050 can you provide an example? There are pandas methods to do that efficiently (i.e without a loop/map/apply)

Comment: To be more specific: data frame contains time stamp. I'd like to find all records where timestamp is greater than X. On those records, apply function to some columns which will give a result to other column(s). (In the example above, x is for time stamp)

Comment: Can you [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/76987365/edit) your question with a reproducible example?

Comment: Question has been updated

Comment: But you didn't provide a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples)

Comment: @user1977050 I updated the code, see it's almost the same, just the condition changes. You can use a condition on multiple columns if needed. No need for `map` or `apply` that are slow.

Comment: im guessing my answer probably slower than yours, but just thought i would throw another solution in the mix :)

Answer (score -1):

Here is a way:

```
df.fillna(df[['x','x']].pow([2,3]).set_axis(list('ab'),axis=1).where(df['Time'].gt(3)))
```

Output:

```
   Time  x   y     a      b
0   0.3  0   1   2.0    3.0
1   1.5  4   5   6.0    7.0
2   2.8  8   9  10.0   11.0
3   3.3  8  13  64.0  512.0
4   4.5  3  17   9.0   27.0
```

Comment: even though the code is performing the scenario, it is very specific and not general

Comment: i think it should be able to work for different situations.

Comment: the solution to use `pow` is very specific. if I need to use more complicated function?